# Generic cached value class mimicking Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, generics, lazy

Before I wrote this I searched and found a number of solutions that make use of a caching provider to handle a set of items. I felt that was too cumbersome of an approach and set out to create a class that could cache a single value, similar to the way [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) manages the initialization of a single value.

I'm having trouble determining the thread-safety of this implementation, specifically where `lock` statements should be used. Can any experts on working with multi-threaded applications spot where I may have gone wrong? Or is this approach sound?

```
public class Cached<T> {
    private readonly TimeSpan _duration;
    private DateTime _expiration;
    private Lazy<T> _value;
    private readonly Func<T> _valueFactory;

    public T Value {
        get {
            // Do I need locking while checking the expiration?
            if (DateTime.Now >= _expiration)
                RefreshValue();

            return _value.Value;
        }
    }

    public Cached(Func<T> valueFactory, TimeSpan duration) {
        _duration = duration;
        _valueFactory = valueFactory;

        RefreshValue();
    }

    private void RefreshValue() {
        // Is this sufficient while updating the expiration and value?
        lock (this) {
            _value = new Lazy<T>(() => _valueFactory());
            _expiration = DateTime.Now.Add(_duration);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `Lazy<T>` for the value getter because it's possible that the cached value will be (1) expensive to load and (2) not immediately needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First off, never lock on `this`. You never know who else is locking on that instance. Conversely, clients don't know that the cache is locking on itself either. For example, this seemingly innocent code would lead to a deadlock:

```
//Thread A
lock(cache)
lock(someObject)
{
    //do something
}

//Thread B
lock(someObject)
{
    //here, the cache will lock on itself.
    //the locks are accidentally taken in reverse order -> deadlock!
    var x = cache.Value;
}
```

That's why it's good practice to lock on a private readonly `object`.
Moving on...

Your current implementation allows the value to be refreshed twice in a row. This is a problem if the resource is expensive to create (and resources worth caching usually are).

Two threads might check whether `DateTime.Now >= _expiration`, then both go into the `RefreshValue` method and execute the critical region in quick sucession. To solve this you can either:

1. move the lock up to the place where the expiration date is being checked.
2. move the expiration check inside the `RefreshValue` method.

I would go with option 2, and add a double-checked lock to avoid hitting the lock every single time:

```
private readonly object _refreshLock = new object();

private void RefreshValueIfNeeded()
{
    if (DateTime.Now >= _expiration)
    {
        lock (_refreshLock)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now >= _expiration)
            {
                _value = new Lazy<T>(_valueFactory);
                _expiration = DateTime.Now.Add(_duration);
            }
        }
    }
}


public T Value
{
    get
    {
        RefreshValueIfNeeded();
        return _value.Value;
    }
}
```

One more thing: you don't need to wrap the value factory into *another* delegate, you can just pass it directly to `Lazy<T>`'s constructor:

```
//change this
new Lazy<T>(() => _valueFactory())
//to
new Lazy<T>(_valueFactory)
```

Comment: Good tip on locking `this`. I'll make that change as you suggested. Would it be enough to `lock (_value)` or should I have a dummy `object` instead?

Comment: If often you have a few threads and a long expiration time compared to the time it takes to create the resource, moving the check outside the lock may make it slower rather than faster.

Comment: Ah okay, never mind, you added in the double-check thing :)

Comment: @BenAaronson Yeah, I gave it a second thought, and I think it's much better to encapsulate the thread-safety strategy along with the refreshing. The double-checked locking will also avoid a perf hit 99% of the time.

Comment: @Yuck locking on `_value` isn't safe either. Let's say the `_value` variable contains object `a`. Thread1 locks on that object `a`, goes into the critical region, makes the `_value` variable point to a new object `b`. Thread2 comes along, attempts to lock on object `b`, and succeeds, and goes into the critical region before Thread1 exits.

Comment: @Yuck - *I'll make that change as you suggested.* - just in case you are unaware of Code Review processes, we have a policy against editing your code in your question after it has been reviewed... [What you can and cannot do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) ... and welcome (back) to Code Review.

Comment: @Yuck the problem is that _value is not immutable. Use a -private- and -readonly- field. Created a dedicated `object` for this is a good practice

Comment: You're right to suggest not to use `lock (this)`, but I don't think your code would deadlock, since `lock` is recursive (you can acquire the lock it multiple times, as long as it's all done from the same thread).

Comment: @svick I've updated my answer with a better example on how locking on `this` can lead to a deadlock.

Comment: @Yuck I've added one more note to my answer, regarding the way you're calling `Lazy<T>`'s constructor.

Answer (score 3):

What you could get is multiple threads calling `RefreshValue`, waiting on that lock, then one at a time they run the code inside the lock. That's inefficient but shouldn't lead to any actual bugs.

If you want to avoid this, you could put a lock on the expiration check. However, I'd suggest profiling this, because this will potentially be hit many times more than `RefreshValue`, and potentially may have a greater performance cost.

Another alternative might be to have the an initial expiration check as it is, then a second, identical one inside the `RefreshValue` lock, returning immediately if it hasn't expired. This will mean most calls will be able to go through without ever hitting the lock, and if multiple threads do end up entering `RefreshValue`one after the other, only one will actually do the expensive value calculation. Again, you should choose between this and one of the other two based on profiling with what you think are reasonable expiration intervals.